# Microsoft Storage Powershell Module 'Get-Disk' doesn't list disks when Failover-Clustering is installed

Tags: powershell, storage, windows-server-2016, ansible, failovercluster

I have 10 disks on a Windows 2016 Server.  If I have the Windows feature 'Failover-Clustering' installed, the [`Get-Disk`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-disk?view=windowsserver2016-ps#notes) cmdlet only reflects two disks - even when the server is not yet part of a cluster.

[image: only two disks show before uninstall]

If I uninstall Failover-Clustering, the other 8 disks appear.

[image: after uninstall, all 10 disks show]

Any ideas on how to allow `Get-Disk` to show the disks properly? I have no intention of making these disks shared resources in the cluster.

I need `Get-Disk` to work properly because Ansible utilizes `Get-Disk` in its `win_format` and `win_initialize` modules.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behaviour. I just deployed a WS2016 VM, added some data disks to it, enabled Failover Clustering... and the disks are just fine.

Comment: Can you actually see the disks in Disk Management? What about `diskpart`?

Comment: Also, how many controllers are you using, and which type? Is there any difference between the disks you can see and the ones you can't see?

Comment: Thanks Massimo - this behavior has suddenly disappeared so im left scratching my head as to what caused it.  For what it's worth the only disks that showed up were the ones on the LSI Logic SAS controller.  The ones that disappeared were on Paravirtual.  I could see the disks in disk management and diskpart though.

I ran into the issue repeatedly destroying/rebuilding the servers like this, then suddenly it just seemed to stop.  I'll be working on it more in the coming weeks and if I have any updates to this question I'll post it here

Comment: Did you (or the OS) install any update? This could very well have been a bug and then have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Do your "missing" disks show up in the output of

```
Get-ClusterAvailableDisk
```

?

Can your ansible scripts be adjusted to either run whatever you need to have them do as to win_format / win_initialize *before* the Clustering feature gets installed and you start to have problems seeing the disks?   Or: can you tweak your scripts to call Get-ClusterAvailableDisk?

Comment: The command (and any other cluster-related command) doesn't work unless the system is actually member of a cluster. The Cluster Service does not start and cannot be started until the system is joined to a cluster.

Comment: Yes, what Massimo said is correct.  I tried the Get-ClusterAvailableDisk but it didn't work until joined to the cluster.  Whereas the behavior I was seeing was only right after cluster service was just installed.